# Get an ini setting in PHP at the command line

Tags: php, linux

On the Linux command line, is it possible to run a command to get a PHP ini settings value?

I understand that I can echo [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) or simply go and inspect the .ini file, but I can’t see a command to run that will display the value directly on the command line.

Answer (score 69):

```
php -i | grep 'my_value'
```

or

```
php -r "echo ini_get('my_value');"
```

or

```
grep 'my_value' /path/to/php.ini
```

Comment: This will use the command line php.ini file though, which will be different from the apache ini file.  Except from the last example and i need to find the ini file location etc first which is what i am trying to avoid in the first place

Comment: Well then no. As far as I'm aware there's no way to invoke the PHP processor that's installed with mod_php for apache via the command line. Either create a file with `phpinfo()` in it and request it via http, or `find / -name php.ini` which will actually be *less* useful if PHP is configure to load additional .ini files. However, the vast majority of the time both the CLI and apache modules use the exact same config.